# Object passed to method has no value?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, database-cursor

I am trying to pass a Scanner object to the method *create()* but inside the method the Scanner object does not have any value. Here is the code if someone has any tips:

```java
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class Instructions
{
    /**
     * Make constructor private so that there cannot be 
     * any instances of the class.
     */
    private Instructions(){}


    public static void operate(String instruction)
    {
        //Get instruction
        Scanner scanString = new Scanner(instruction);
        scanString.useDelimiter(" |;");
        String next;

        //Scan and operate
        if(scanString.hasNext())
        {
            next = scanString.next();

            if(next.equals("CREATE"))
            {
                create(scanString);
            }
            else if(next.equals(".EXIT"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }   
        }

        scanString.close();
    }

    private static void create(Scanner scanString)
    {
        //Program reaches here with what should be "DATABASE db_1"
        //left in scanString

        String next;

        if(scanString.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("HERE"); //Never reaches this

            next = scanString.next();

            if(next.equals("DATABASE"))
            {
                createDatabase(scanString);
            }
            else if(next.equals("TABLE"))
            {
                createTable(scanString);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Instruction " + next + " not recognized. Skipping instruction." );
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createDatabase(Scanner scanString)
    {
        File database;

        if(scanString.hasNext())
        {
            database = new File(scanString.next());

            if(!database.exists())
            {
                //Make a database file
                try
                {
                    database.createNewFile();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("!Failed to create database " + database.toString() + 
                    "because it already exists.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createTable(Scanner scanString)
    {

    }
}
```

The input file I'm reading from has the form:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_1;
```

I am trying to figure out why that when I call scanString.hasNext() in the create() method, scanString.hasNext() is not returning true when there are two more tokens left after the first delimiter?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Scanner object does not have any value"? Please provide a **complete** code example that we can compile and run. Also show an example run of your program, including both input and output. And explain what output you want instead.

Comment: What are your inputs and excepted output ? It is not clear what you want .

Comment: I updated the post, I hope it's a little more clear what I'm asking thanks guys!

Comment: why are you using `scanString.useDelimiter(" |;");` ? Are you sure that just `splitting` the command `CREATE DATABASE db_1;` would not be easier

Comment: oh maybe something like: `String[] array = instruction.split(" |;", 0);` that might work too

Comment: What is the `|` for?

Comment: I just tested by calling `operate` with the input `"CREATE DATABASE db_1;"` - Worked as expected; `HERE` printed to the console: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/oJzcQH)

Comment: That's weird mine isn't reaching that print statement. Maybe it's because I'm running Java 11.0.1? But I doubt it.

Comment: @BrandonMain Something tells me your input isn't what you expect. Did you double check to see if your data was as expected? A comment in your code mentions `what should be "DATABASE db_1"` - It SHOULD be, but did you check to make sure that it was? You should really use a debugger for this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes if I print `System.out.println(next)` right after calling `next = scanString.next()` in the `operate` method, I get the expected output of the split instruction.

Comment: `next` in the `operate` method should return to  you the value `CREATE`; you're saying it prints `CREATE`, yeah? If not, the issue could stem from there. If it does print only `CREATE` (prints properly), jump to the `create` method and above where you check `hasNext`, do `System.out.println(scanString.nextLine());` - What is your output? Once again, a debugger would be a better tool for this; wouldn't need to rely on `println` to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. In the class that was calling the `Instructions.operate()` static method I was declaring  scanner object on the input file _outside_ of the `try{}catch(){}` statement and by changing that it works now. Not sure why though but it does haha. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(instruction);
```

This creates a `Scanner` that uses the given `String` as input.

```
next = new String(scanString.next());
```

This reads the input based on the Scanner's delimiters which defaults to whitespace. If the input string contains no whitespace, then this call will be return the entire input string.

Note: you should never use `new String()`. Here you can just do `next = scanString.next()`.

Comment: "*You should never use `new String`*" - What about converting a `byte[]` into a `String`?

Comment: And even with `new String(someString)` there are obscure cases where it is necessary.  The word "never" is an overstatement.